# Why is RequireJS not working when using priority?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

When using RequireJS without "priority" it works:

```
require(

  {},

  [
    'js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js',
    'js/libs/utils.js',
    'js/app/app.index.js',
    'js/app/app.framework.js',
    'js/app.modules/app.modules.navigation.js'
  ],

  function() {
    require.ready(function() {
      console.log('require is done and dom is ready');
      app.name = 'myApp';
      app.init();
    });   
  }

);
```

But once i add "priority", it stops working:

```
require(

  {
    priority: [
      'js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js',
      'js/libs/utils.js',
      'js/app/app.blueprint.js',
      'js/app/app.framework.js'
    ]
  },

  [
    'js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js',
    'js/libs/utils.js',
    'js/app/app.index.js',
    'js/app/app.framework.js',
    'js/app.modules/app.modules.navigation.js'
  ],

  function() {
    require.ready(function() {
      console.log('require is done and dom is ready');
      app.name = 'myApp';
      app.init();
    });   
  }

);
```

What am i doing wrong?

p.s. And for anyone wondering why I do not use the RequireJS-jQuery, is a preference thing =]

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Are you getting an error message? What does your console say?

Comment: i get nothing. The logs i added (which showed when "property" is removed) are gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was a small bug in requirejs which James Burke fixed in the latest commit of requirejs: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/commit/9be3d7d01db380c1014d9cc393be2762e3c78044

It will go in the next release possibly in the upcoming weeks.

Reference: 
http://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/4d8f5bce44dff57d